# How to run a loop at a defined interval in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web project, and I need a loop that will loop every 5 or 6 seconds. I want to be able to activate a block of code to change part of the page. How can I do this without crashing the page?

Comment: Wasn't really sure how to say it...

Comment: Do you have any code already written? Give us something to go off of.

Comment: Look into jQuery timer plugin or `.delay()` function https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript has a [native setInterval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) that allows you to run a specific block of code at a defined interval.

Try something like this:

```
var someFunction = function(){
  // define your loop here
};

var interval = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds is 5 seconds.

setInterval(someFunction, interval);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the native setInterval function

You can get more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Say the block of code you wish to activate is a function called `everyFiveSeconds`

Your code would be:
`setInterval(everyFiveSeconds, 5000);`
The interval is counted in milliseconds